# Customizing XmlAdapter for generated wsimport files

Tags: web-services, jax-ws

I'm doing contract-first web services using JAX-WS to generate the files from WSDL. We are using the *jaxb-bindings.xml* to map the XML to Java using custom adapter. However wsimport generated another adapter on the fly which implements `XmlAdapter` and delegate it to our custom adapter.

Is there a way to customized the wsimport configuration to use our own custom `XmlAdapter`?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the attribute " -b " to the wsimport command to specify a custom file for the binding, and here is an article about how to do so with examples:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html

Comment: My issue is not with JAXB binding itself, but with the class generated by jax-ws wsimport.